# When ftruncate to 0 first disk block release?

Tags: c, linux, windows

When do breathable file from 0B to ~1MB first block freed?
I wonder if there be performance differences between:

1. ftruncate(handle,1B)(or SetfilePointerEx in windows) to
2. ftruncate(handle,0B)
   when the file empty from data.

Comment: The advantage of ftruncate is it doesn't touch the file contents, only the block allocation.  Try each and measure.

Comment: The best way to check for performance differences is to implement, run and measure both variants.

Comment: I wonder if first block freed when ftruncate to 0. if so, ftruncate to 1 have better performance.